# Dictionary .Add not supported C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm using a dictionary in my code as follows:

```
var allValues = new Dictionary<string, int>();
         
while (//condition))
{
    response = // call to a method that returns some values of type Dictionary<string, int> 
    allValues.Add(response);
}
```

When I use .Add I get the following error:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Iterate the key-value pair from `response` to add into `allValues` or `allValues = response;`.

Comment: You cannot add a dictionary to a dictionary, you should get the key and value from the response and add that

Comment: Updated: `allValues = response;`, this solution may incorrect as it is inside the loop and will be overwritten for each loop iteration.

Comment: Your screenshot shows the method signature with the two expected parameters. But you pass a single Dictionary parameter instead.

Answer (score 1):

A `Dictionary` can be iterated over as collection of key/value pairs, so you can do this:

```
while (condition)
{
    response = // call to a method that returns some values of type Dictionary<string, int> 
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in response)
    {
        allValues.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

Assuming `response` is itself a `Dictionary`

Answer (score 0):

You can add key value pair to dictionary. Try below code as an example.

```
var allValues = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            int diccounter = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                allValues.Add("a" + diccounter, diccounter++);
            }
```

Comment: @mjwills yes, I have already mentioned it as an example.